# Changing the value of hidden input field to PHP variable with AJAX success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following hidden input field with a dynamic value.

```
<input id='max' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $num_rows; ?>'>
```

I'm wanting to update that value based on $num_rows that are returned from a `ajax_load_profile_friends.php` page.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $("#viewAllFriends").click(function(){
        counter = counter+16;

            $.ajax({

                url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{'username':username, 'num_friends':num_friends, 'counter':counter},

                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#data_friends').html(data);
                        $('#max').val("??");
                            }

                    });
            });
```

With each successive click of View More Friends button, I get a new value for `$num_rows`.  Being new to Ajax I'm not sure how to return it to the success function and then update the `value` in the hidden input.

`$num_rows` returns like this `$num_rows = $result->num_rows;` in `ajax_load_profile_friends.php`.

This is part of a larger problem I was having earlier but have narrowed it down to this and tried to simplify my question.  Any help, examples, links would be super!

Comment: so what is your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the PHP so it returns JSON. So instead of

```
echo $html;
```

it should do:

```
echo json_encode(array('num_rows' => $num_rows, 'html' => $html));
```

Then in the JavaScript you can extract both return values:

```
        $.ajax({

            url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{'username':username, 'num_friends':num_friends, 'counter':counter},

            success: function(data) {
                $('#data_friends').html(data.html);
                $('#max').val(data.num_rows);
            }

        });
```

Comment: hmmm...The button goes dead with this script and I get some console errors.

Comment: Is `#viewAllFriends` inside `#data_friends`?

Comment: If you're overwriting any elements that have event bindings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: no `#viewAllFriends` is just below the `#data_friends div` .

Comment: Then I can't think of any reason why the button would go dead. Unless there's a syntax error that's causing this function not to run at all.

Comment: `data->html` and `data->num_rows` should have been `data.html` and `data.num_rows`, of course.

Comment: Maybe I'm not implementing this correctly:  `echo json_encode(array('num_rows' => $num_rows, 'html' => $html));`

Comment: The errors I'm getting are: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token` and `GET about:blank net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: There's no `about:blank` in my answer, that's not related.

Comment: `data->htm` and `data->num_rows` should have been `data.html` and `data.num_rows`.  I changed this and am not getting the errors now, but the button is still unresponsive.  it no longer runs my queries.

Comment: Did you replace `$html` with the actual variable in your script that holds the output? That was just intended as a placeholder.

Comment: I just did that yes.  It's sitting in a while loop and returning the following:  `$html =  "<a class='profile-img-item' href='" . $data_row['username'] . "'><img src='" . $data_row['profile_pic'] . "' title='" . $data_row['username'] . "'> </a>";`  It's only friend at a time now.  weird

Comment: Does the Network tab show that the AJAX call is being sent? Do you see the response coming back?

Comment: It's only returning one friend in` #data_friends` now and the hidden input is still sitting at the default value of 8.

Comment: my success function is as follows:  `success: function(data) {$('#data_friends').html(data.html);$('#max').val(data.num_rows);}`

Comment: I switched it back so that `echo json_encode(array('num_rows' => $num_rows));` and removed  `dataType: 'json',`  The queries run fine again and my div populates with user images, but the value in the hidden input field remains unchanged.  It is echoing `{"num_rows":43}` with each successive click up to 43 which is the total number of records.  is there a way to get this to update `$('#max').val(data.num_rows);` in the success function without changing the `dataType`?

Comment: You could call `JSON.parse(data)` in the success function, but that's what jQuery does when you use `dataType: 'json'`. If you don't include the HTML in the JSON array, then you won't have anything to put in `#data_friends`. I can't figure out why it's not working when you follow my answer exactly.

Comment: Hello Barmar.  Me neither.  I did raise a new question based on your method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879979/php-variables-not-returning-to-success-ajax-jquery-post-correctly-using-json-enc/54880010?noredirect=1#comment96531318_54880010    when I declare `$html='';`  and concatenate `$html .=`  I get a return of 40 records, but not 43, weird.  I also, still do not get my hidden input value to change.  The new question shows my `ajax_load_profile_friends.php` in more detail.  Do you see anything here where I might be missing with `json_encode`?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong there, it really should work. I suspect the problem has something to do with your HTML. Is your web page accessible on the Internet?